# Regular expression to capture repeated word (more than one 2 repetition in text)

Tags: java, regex

I would like to write a program in JAVA, to capture words which repeated more than 2 times in a text content.

- This repetition can be 3, 4 , 5 or many.
- The repetition might spread around the text and doesn't have any order.
- I need to keep the times of repeat as well.
- It should not be case sensitive.

for instance:
the blue book over The red pen is the biggest book I ever seen.
Result: the:3

What can be the proper regular expression pattern for this matter?

Comment: Well first, do you choose the words? Or is every word that is 3x or more going to be outputted

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper  every word that is 3x or more going to be outputted

Comment: I doubt that regex is correct tool for this. Consider using regex only to find/split words but store them in collection like `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Well I recommend you do a little research on your own. Not to sound rude, but you need to do a little digging on your own before bringing your question here. I would recommend looking for delimiters or splitting words, they would be good places to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to solve this problem by regex I would suggest following algorithm:

1. Split your sentence into words (using white spaces) and store their lowercase version in a `List<String>`.
2. Declare a map as `HashMap<String, Integer>`.
3. Iterate over your words `List` and keep storing in the map.
4. If `Map` didn't have an entry of the word then `key=word, value=1`
5. Otherwise increment value by 1 giving you frequency of each word.
6. Every time frequency goes above 2 store that word in your output `HashSet<String>`
7. At the end of loop just print `HashSet<String>`

Comment: I tried this solution. However it is case sensitive. That means "The" is different from "the". However I want this to be not case sensitive.

Comment: see updated step 1, you can lowercase words right after `String#split`

Comment: str.toLowerCase(); Did the job! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for regexes, unless for splitting a text in words. Next you just have to use a Map, with the key being the word, and value being the number or repetitions.

When done, you just scan the Map to find the most repeated word.